# ogr2ogr - Looping through files in a folder on a Mac

Tags: ogr2ogr, mac

I am attempting to use OGR2ORG on Mac OS X to loop through 30 shapefiles, change their projection and save the files into a new directory. I am new to using Macs and the OGR2OGR command line environment.

The original files are in /data/ChicagoBaseLayers/clipped.  I would like the reprojected layers to go to /data/ChicagoBaseLayers/Projected.

After navigating to the 'clipped' directory on the command line, I tried

for %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:3857 -s_srs EPSG:4326 /Users/stevenchong/data/ChicagoBaseLayers/Projected/%f Users/stevenchong/data/ChicagoBaseLayers/clipped/%f

but I get the error message: syntax error near unexpected token `('

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks a lot like a windows style 'for loop' and if you enter it in one single line, without ';' in place of where the newlines need to be, you could get some errors.

Try doing it in Linux style!

```
cd /Users/stevenchong/data/ChicagoBaseLayers/clipped; for f in *.shp; do ogr2ogr -t_srs "EPSG:3857" -s_srs "EPSG:4326" ../Projected/${f} ${f}; done
```

That's probably a better way to enter it into the terminal on one line.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the helpful explanation too!